# not getting songs from album

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I was trying to get songs from album in my app. I wrote code below with some help on internet but now I'm getting all items as 0. I dont know why I'm getting 0.

```
public void songs()
{
    String name;
    long genreId;
    Uri uri;
    Cursor genrecursor;
    Cursor tempcursor;
    String[] proj1 = { android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM};
    String[] proj2 = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
            ,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};

    genrecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj1, null, null, null);
    if (genrecursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            name = String.valueOf(genrecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM));
            Log.i("Tag-album name", genrecursor.getString(Integer.parseInt(name)));

            name = String.valueOf(genrecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID));
            genreId = Long.parseLong(genrecursor.getString(Integer.parseInt(name)));
            uri = MediaStore.Audio.Genres.Members.getContentUri("external", genreId);

            tempcursor = managedQuery(uri, proj2, null, null, null);
            Log.i("Tag-Number of songs for this album", tempcursor.getCount() + "");
            if (tempcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    name = String.valueOf(tempcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    String art = String.valueOf(tempcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
                    String path = String.valueOf(tempcursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                    Log.i("Tag-Song name", tempcursor.getString(Integer.parseInt(name)));
                    albumInfo s = new albumInfo(name,art,path);
                    albumSongList.add(s);
                } while (tempcursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } while (genrecursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: call `DatabaseUtils#dumpCurrentRow()` in the first `do ... while` loop, what do you see on the `logcat`?

Comment: it gives me album names only but not their songs,it shows 0 songs.

Comment: you need to use `Uri` returned by `MediaStore.Audio.Media#getContentUri()`

Comment: did you call `MediaStore.Audio.Media#getContentUri()` ?

Comment: **uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(String.valueOf(genreId));**

Comment: did you read the documentation for `getContentUri` at all? ok nevermind: https://pastebin.com/raw/9V5vq4at

Comment: songs are there too, what do you see on the `logcat` when you run it?

Comment: but in order to show it on a list view you dont have to iterate both `Cursor`s in the while loop - you can use `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` instead just in 20-30 lines of code

Comment: i said that you DONT have to make two `while` loops for two `Cursor` iterations - instead use `SimpleCursorTreeAdapter` - what adapter are you using now?

Comment: i can post the answer if you want.and please give some i would love to learn to learn about SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: run [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/3EtCmasY) sample code in your `Activity#onCreate` method

Answer (score 0):

i did this.

```
    Uri uri= MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] columns = {
            MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM};

    Cursor cursor =getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().
            query(uri, columns, null,
                    null, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.v("bbb",
                    cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM)));
            v=cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    // I want to list down song in album Rolling Papers (Deluxe Version)

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
    };


    Intent i=getIntent();
    final String value=i.getStringExtra("sol");
    String [] x=new String[]{value};
    String where = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM + "=?";
    Log.e("syn",v);
    String whereVal[] = {v};

    String orderBy = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;

    cursor =getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            column, where, x,null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.v("Vipul",
                    cursor.getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            String name=cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String art=cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID));
            String path=cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));


            albumInfo s = new albumInfo(name,art,path); // EXCLUDED
            albumSongList.add(s);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

}
```

Comment: first one i was just checking.